# Django (uwsgi) + nginx hangs on curl requests

Tags: nginx, django, curl

I am trying to debug a problem where a request done with curl hangs. The website renders fine if I open it through any web browser. I can't find anything suspicious into the log files as well.

I've enabled logging `error_log info;` but I don't see anything into the nginx log files.

Here is an example request:

```
$ curl -v -o test.txt https://www.happyworld.bg
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.happyworld.bg/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 172.104.135.164...
* Connected to www.happyworld.bg (172.104.135.164) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 604 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

.... Certificate info ...
    * ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1

> GET / HTTP/1.1
>   Host: www.happyworld.bg
>   User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
>   Accept: */*
>
> ```
>   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> < Server: nginx/1.13.6
> < Date: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 14:18:56 GMT
> < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
> < Content-Length: 32484
> < Connection: keep-alive
> < Vary: Cookie
> < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> < Cache-Control: max-age=600
> < Expires: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 14:28:56 GMT
> < Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains
> < X-Frame-Options: DENY
> < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> < 
> { [15988 bytes data]
>  74 32484   74 24037    0     0   2563      0  0:00:12  0:00:09  0:00:03
> ```

and after some time I get:

```
* Closing connection 0
curl: (18) transfer closed with 8447 bytes remaining to read
```

Into the application log file, I can see only:

```
[pid: 12406|app: 0|req: 1/1] ........... () {42 vars in 486 bytes} [Thu Aug 30 14:15:03 2018] GET / => generated 24037 bytes in 85 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 6 headers in 193 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Here is example of the virtual block configuration:

```
upstream wagtail { server 127.0.0.1:3002; }

location @CMS {
  include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass wagtail;
  uwsgi_param Host $host;
  uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
}
```

Any clue what might be causing it or if I am missing something?